# How does this program work? How's firstGreaterEqual method working

Tags: python, search, binary-search

I'm new to stack overflow. I hope this question meets the guide lines.
Thnakyou.!

```
     class Solution:
        def searchRange(self, nums, target):
            """
            :type nums: List[int]
            :type target: int
            :rtype: List[int]
            """
            start = self.firstGreaterEqual(nums, target)
            if start==len(nums) or nums[start]!=target:
                return [-1, -1]
            return [start, self.firstGreaterEqual(nums, target+1)-1]
        def firstGreaterEqual(self, nums, target):
            lo, hi = 0, len(nums)
            while lo<hi:
                mid = (hi+lo)//2
                if nums[mid]<target:
                    lo = mid + 1
                else:
                    hi = mid
            return lo


    Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 6
    Output: [-1,-1]

Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8
Output: [3,4]
```

This program is to search for a range
[link to the program](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-for-a-range/description/)
This solution has the best run time.
I'm finding it hard to understand the logic behind it.
It is using binary search but I'm not fully understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is basically working on the principle of binary search like you pointed out.

Here is the algorithm break down in simple terms

- First you find the first occurence of the target that you are looking for

  - If there is no occurence of the target, return [-1, -1]
- Then find the first occurence of `target+1`, suppose that occurence is stored in variable `end`, then the last occurence of the original `target` will be `end -1

  **First you find the first occurence of the target that you are looking**
  Example array `nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8`
- `lo = 0`, `hi = len(nums)`,`mid = (hi+lo)//2`
- Now you search the middle of the array, here `mid = 3`
- The element at nums[3] is 8, which is the same as taget
- This is the starting index, return it and store in the value `start`

**Now since we got the first occurence we proceed to the next phase**

**Then find the first occurence of `target+1`**

1. `lo = 0`, `hi = len(nums)`,`mid = (hi+lo)//2`, `target+1 = 9`
2. Now you search the middle of the array, here `mid = 3`
3. The element at nums[3] is 8, which is less than `target+1`, so we set `low = mid +1`
4. Next we set `mid = (hi+lo)//2`, which is 5
5. The element at nums[5] is 10, which is more than `target+1`, so we set `hi = mid`
6. After the previous step, we get out of `while loop` since the condition `while lo<hi` evaluates to False
7. REturn `lo` as the ending index

Now we have start = 3, and end = 5, so we return [start, end-1], i.e. [3,4]

Reference:

- [GeeksForGeeks blog post for same problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-first-and-last-positions-of-an-element-in-a-sorted-array/)